# How to convert DIB to TPNGObject?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dib, tpngimagelist

I have a DIB handle. How can I convert it to `TPNGObject` with preserving its transparency?

**EDIT :**
I use method 2 in this solution [Here](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/LeadToolsConversions.TXT)

but the bitmap resulted is not transparent even if i set its `Transparent` Flag with true

Comment: Which Delphi and which PNG lib?

Comment: i use Delphi 7 , but i don't understand what lib do u mean, and thanks for you concern :)

Comment: There are a number of PNG libraries in common use with D7. Answer may depend on which one you use.

Comment: I'm sorry David but how can i know the lib? i just use pngimage in the uses section and define a TPNGOBject. is there a way to know which library i use..

Comment: Delphi 7 can not handle PNG by default. So you have a thirdparty lib which handles and registers the PNG-pictures. Open the file "pngimage.pas" and see which lib you have.

Comment: It will say in the source code. Who is the author. I'm not expert, perhaps the name `TPNGObject` is sufficient ID.

Comment: Gustavo Huffenbacher Daud si the author version 1.564

Comment: http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=6929

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to start out something like this:

```
var
  lpbi: PBitmapInfoHeader;
begin
  // Get DIB header info from DIB handle
  lpbi := PBitmapInfoHeader(GlobalLock(hdIB));
end;
```

Then, if it's a 32 bit image, it will have an alpha channel, which you'll use for your transparency data.

Then, you copy the RGB data to the PNG object's scanline and the alpha data to the alpha scanline.

Comment: I use this code to get the bitmap, how can i manipulate it to extract the png image(the bitmap image resulted is not transparent even if i set its Transparent property to true)

Comment: @Sara, yes, the TBitmap only supports a single transparent color, and it's whatever color matches the first pixel (upper left corner). Gustavo Daud's TPNGObject supports a full alpha channel. You use the scanline and alpha scanline properties to copy the data over to, pixel by pixel.

Comment: Thanks Marcus but can you help me in how to copy the image data